# After click return to initial state

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I got a question regarding changing elements in the DOM. I got a situation that whenever I click on the button it will show a div. After 2 seconds the initial div is replaced by another div which also got a function call that removes the div again.

Now comes the tricky part. What I want is that whenever I hide the div again, the third click on the button will show the div again.

Let me explain a bit more. Imagine that I got the following situation:

- First mouse click on button 1 (Result: shows red div)
- Second mouse click on button 1 (Result: hide red div)
- Third mouse click on button 1 (shows the div again)

The third bullet is the tricky one. How can I do that? Because when I click for the third time on button 1 it does not show anything anymore because I did not change it back to the original state

The code that I have so far [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2mvqmtwq/)

```
function Test(){
    var target = window.event.target || window.event.srcElement;
    console.log(target);

    var content = arguments[0];
    console.log(content);

    $( "body" ).append( "<div class='red'>"+content+"</div>" );

    setTimeout(function(){
          $( ".press" ).replaceWith( "<button class='press' onclick='UnTest()'>button 1</button>" );
    }, 2000);
}

function UnTest(){
    $( ".red").remove();
}
```

**Please note** that due to implementation restrictions I can not check within my Function if the button is clicked (eq. `$(".red").click()`)

Comment: So you want to toggle the visibility of a div on and off from clicking a button?

Comment: The thing is that the DIV is not already in the DOM. I set it with the function. In my example toggle visibility would work I guess. But would it also work if I got multiple buttons each pointing to the same function test with each a different parameter? @depperm

Comment: can you always have the div in the DOM, with an initial class that make it invisible, so when the button is clicked you toggle that class?

Comment: No, you have to see as a tooltip function. You create the tooltip object in the dom and when you hide the tooltip, the tooltip will be destroyed and not longer be visible in your DOM @YerkoPalma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you could accomplish this, but a quick solution might be just toggling the `onclick` attribute of the button (rather than replacing it entirely).

```
// In setTimeout
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.press').attr('onclick', 'UnTest()');
}, 2000);

function UnTest(){
    $( ".red").remove();
    $('.press').attr('onclick', 'Test("one")');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2mvqmtwq/1/

This will also allow you to add multiple `.red` divs (similar to the original fiddle) and then remove with a single click (which another answer does not take into account, instead treating it as a simple visibility toggle).

**Edit**: For multiple buttons/instances (per your comment), you'll need an identifier of sort. Your original code made it easy by declaring the `target`, which we can use. Let's say we have three buttons:

```
<button class="press" onclick="Test('one')">button 1</button>
<button class="press" onclick="Test('two')">button 2</button>
<button class="press" onclick="Test('three')">button 3</button>
```

Our updated JS doesn't change too much, other than referencing the string value we passed (which you declare as `content`):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(target).attr('onclick', 'UnTest("' + content + '")');
}, 2000);
```

As well as referencing the `target` you've declared at the top (which allows us to keep each button instance unique).

Here's the updated fiddle with all the changes I made (additional parameters, scoped class names for the red boxes, etc):

https://jsfiddle.net/2mvqmtwq/9/

Comment: Yep, this a good solution. But how would you apply your code if I have ten buttons calling the same function (for example calling a tooltip function). Then how would you do `$('.press').attr('onclick', 'Test("one")');` where the value `one` is the variable depending on which button you click?

Comment: @Rotan075 - Updated with the multiple buttons use case.

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable to count the number of clicks, which is initially equal to 0. Then, each time you click the button, you increase the variable by 1 and check if the variable is odd or even. If it's odd, you add the `div`, if it's even you remove the `div`:

```
var clicked = 0;

function Test() {
    clicked++;
    var content = arguments[0];
    if (clicked % 2 === 1) {
        $("body").append("<div class='red'>" + content + "</div>");
    } else {
        $(".red").remove();
        clicked = 0;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2mvqmtwq/5/

Tip: you can reset the variable back to 0 when it's even.

Comment: Even more better `clicked` could be just a `Boolean` variable, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/2mvqmtwq/6/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dead simple fix. I think we can do this whole thing a lot more cleanly with some refactoring. But since you mention implementation restraints, I don't want to offer a solution that might break those restraints.

Simply add logic to your UnTest() function

```
function UnTest(){
    $( ".red").remove();
    $( ".press" ).replaceWith( "<button class='press' onclick='Test(\"hello\")'>button 1</button>" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about writing some clean code, avoiding inline event handlers?

What you could probably do is:

- First click: add the `div`
- Next click onwards: check if the `div` already exists. If yes, simply toggle it's display as opposed to removing it.

This is only a demo as to how this could be done. This one also works for multiple buttons/divs. As I said earlier, I have removed inline event handlers and added the div class and function params as data-attributes. Feel free to edit the code to suit your needs.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".press", function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $div = $("div." + $this.data("class"));
    
    if ($div.length) {
        $div.toggle();
        return;
    }

    $( "body" ).append( $("<div/>", {
        'class': $this.data("class"),
        'html': $this.data("param")
    }) );
});
```

```css
button{ margin:10px}
div {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
}
.red {
    background-color:red;
}
.blue {
    background-color:blue;
}
.green {
    background-color:green;
}
.orange {
    background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="press" data-param="one" data-class="red">button 1</button>
<button class="press" data-param="two" data-class="blue">button 2</button>
<button class="press" data-param="three" data-class="green">button 3</button>
<button class="press" data-param="four" data-class="orange">button 4</button>
```